# Realised the answer to my question while I was typing - still ask it?

Tags: discussion

I just started asking a question and, in the process of typing it up and organising my thoughts, I worked out the answer - this has happened before and I suspect I'm not the only person it's happened to.

Is it still worth typing up an answer to it and putting it up on the site?  My thinking is that if I struggled with it for long enough to think "Only Stack Overflow can save me now" then others might as well and if its a bad or obvious question - and just me not thinking straight - it'll eventually be downvoted off anyway.  Plus, the various guidance on self-answered questions seems to support it.  On the flipside, it feels somehow like it would be "clogging up" the site as this wasn't, after all, a topic that I needed help with.

Comment: Depends about how your question depicts a specific programming problem that might be useful to be found in future research.

Comment: well... in theory it's a good idea and if the question and answer are useful then you'll come out ahead, both gaining rep and helping other people. but... in practice, I haven't seen many self answer cases lately that came out ahead.

Comment: If you decide to post and self answer, make absolutely sure that it isn't a duplicate or easily researched.

Comment: It's very hard to write a good question when you've already got the answer because you have to include enough information in the question to make it not low quality or poorly researched, but if you included everything you have then you'd be answering it in the question.

Comment: OverMeta: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*If* the answer is correct, will likely be helpful to future readers, *and* isn't a duplicate, yes, answering your own question in a case like this is a good idea. If you're actually the first person to ask this question, you answering it contributes to the site and helps future users (and of course possibly nets you more rep).

Make sure though that the question hasn't already been asked. Having a question closed as a dupe because of insufficient research is bad and just adds unnecessary bloat to the site.

---

And just as an add-on, the "I started writing an answer, and solved my own problem in the process" idea *is* common; at least to me. I think that it shows that you're actually putting effort into asking your question. If I'm having a hard time debugging something, it's not uncommon for me to open Notepad++ and begin writing a question. Just writing down the debugging steps and what you've learned from debugging is often enough to get me thinking about things I've missed.

Comment: Don't forget the question *has to be of use to other people*. If the solution is, for example, a simple typo, then it's better to abandon it.

Comment: Of course someone else might still answer your question even if you knew the answer when you posted.

Comment: _"Having a question closed as a dupe because of insufficient research is bad and just adds unnecessary bloat to the site."_ - is this really true? Asking the same question in multiple ways means more chance of the next person googling their question and getting a match.

Comment: @Mr.Boy This was three years ago, so obviously I've lost the mindset I had when I wrote that. I'll say though that yes, having multiple "handles" to a duplicate is a good thing, since it increases the chance of it being found. That doesn't mean however that a poorly researched question is fine just because it ended up being a viable "handle". Unless that dupe is truly difficult to find, a poorly researched question is just one more thing that gets put into a queue that needs to be reviewed, one more thing for mods/privileged users to sort through, and one more thing to store.

Comment: @Mr.Boy For the sake of maintaining quality, all questions should be well-asked. Not only does that help prevent us from degrading to the crap-state that many other sites have fallen to, well-researched questions often contain more search-terms that make them better "handles". "Give me the answer even though I haven't looked myself" doesn't give much for Google to match on.

Comment: Or at least that's how I see it. You obviously have a lot of experience with the network, so I may be missing some aspect. I just personally dislike poorly researched questions in general. When I'm in the mood to be helpful, there's nothing worse than needing to sort through tons of awful questions; half of which could have been answered if the OP simply searched for the title they gave the question.